# Maximize Microsoft Web and Database with 2 servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis, windows-server-2012, mssqlft

I need a best technique to boost the performance and availability for the web and database server. My problem is I only can afford two 2 dedicated servers total.

I like to take a full advantage of the two servers by installing the NBL to help the IIS to distribute the traffic. I believe I will have a problem with the MS SQL 2008 Standard edition with Failover option.

My question is:
    Does the NBL cause conflicts with the SQL 2008 Standard with the Failover and doesn't my settings below causing any conflict with the database settings.

```
Server settings are:
    Server 1  - SQL 2008 R2 Standard Edition with NBL installed, IIS, SQL Standard with Failover
    Server 2  - SQL 2008 R2 Standard Edition with NBL installed, IIS, SQL Standard with Failover.
```

I believe I have to remove the NBL to work the server work property, this is a waste of resource. I understood that the SQL 2008 Standard  do not support scale-out feature. Moving from standard to enterprise edition would be too expensive.

Comment: SQL Server Fail-over cluster is fault tolerance solution, do not confuse it with a Web-Server NLB cluster which is a  fault tolerance/Scale-out solution.

Comment: I do understand those options, I believe if I use both options at the same time it will cause some kind of problem that is why I am looking for suggestions/solutions to this problem.

Comment: You mean you'll have two web servers with NLB configured and a sql server failover cluster with two nodes? They should work just fine, standard edition will support it too.

Comment: I only have 2 servers total that is including the web and database. Will your settings work if I only have 2 servers, would the NLB mess up the writing/reading for the SQL.

Comment: On MS website said " Network Load Balancing (NLB) feature in Windows Server 2008 R2 enhances the availability and scalability of Internet server applications such as those used on Web, FTP, firewall, proxy, virtual private network (VPN), and other mission-critical servers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS SQL Standard Failover option will not work on the MS Windows Server Standard version, only the enterprise and datacenter editions can support the failover.
Ref: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770625%28v=ws.10%29.aspx